# Pyqt5 Html to PDF(qbytearray)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

the printopdf callback function does not return anything, the callback returns an empty object, but I can't see the error in the function.

the code is below:

```
    def _handleLoadFinished(self, ok):
        def _QWebEngineCallback(s):
            print(s) 
        if ok:  
            s = QByteArray()       
            self.printToPdf(_QWebEngineCallback(s),self._layout)
```

Comment: Callbacks are always references, not their direct calls. Change to `self.printToPdf(_QWebEngineCallback, self.layout)`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, it looks like this:

```
def _QWebEngineCallback(self,s: bytearray):
        pdfs.append(s)
        if not self._fetchNext():
            QtWidgets.QApplication.quit()
    def _handleLoadFinished(self, ok):
        if ok:          
            self.printToPdf(self._QWebEngineCallback,self._layout)
```